# how to automate a series of search and replace operation in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am having a file in which there are number of lines which i have to remove. These lines can be distinguished using regular expression and thus utilizing series of search and replace i am able to remove them.

Now i have to repeat the same task a number of times. So i am looking for a way that i don't need to go through this series of replace again & again. Is there any way to batch/script these series of replace into a single command.

I tried doing so by recording a macro, but does not seems to work.

Comment: If you have a set of regular expressions, why must you use notepad++? For instance, you might be able to use the `[regex]` class to do the work you need.

Comment: well, notepad++ is what i am looking for, as i am mostly working using this tool.  What exactly do you mean by [regex] class??

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. There is a `[regex]` class in *PowerShell* which you might be able to use.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [Python Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/) plug-in, if you're familiar with Python.
If you're not familiar with Python, you will be it in no time.
Doing such kinds of automation is a fingersnip with that plug-in.
And if you can't get something to work, you'll find help at the
support forum of that plug-in.

[At least one example link about regex replacement via the plug-in](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/forums/forum/1199074/topic/4667045).

Besides I'm using replacement macros in N++ myself. Did you try with
the complex singletabbed "Find/Replace" dialog or with the simple "Replace"
tab of the multitabbed find dialog, which also supports regex? The latter one
works for me. I didn't try the 1st one tho.

Answer (score 2):

Sample script [Multiples_SR.py](https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/blob/master/scripts/Samples/Multiples_SR.py) (see [discussion](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/16942/pythonscript-any-ready-pyscript-to-replace-one-huge-set-of-regex-phrases-with-others/23)) from [Python Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/) plugin sample scripts collection does what you need.

From the explanation of the script:

This script :

- Reads an existing `"SR_List.txt"` file, of the CURRENT directory, containing a list of SEARCH/REPLACEMENT strings, ONE PER line
- Selects, one at a time, a COUPLE of SEARCH and REPLACEMENT regexes/expressions/strings/characters
- Executes this present S/R on CURRENT edited file, in NOTEPAD++
- Loop till the END of the file

Any PURE BLANK line or COMMENT line, beginning with '#', of the "SR_list.txt" file, is simply IGNORED

For EACH line, in the "SR_List.txt" file, the format is

```
<DELIMITER><SEARCH regex><DELIMITER><REPLACE regex><DELIMITER>
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a closing `>` in your format example?

Comment: You are right. Thank you!