# copy single line to multiple lines

Tags: notepad++, string-matching

**The text file has the following:**

```
copy bundles\track_australia\part_054\snds.bundle
 bundles\track_italy\part_052\snds.bundle
 bundles\track_singapore\part_052\snds.bundle
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_054\snds.bundles.bundle
 bundles\track_belgium\part_025\snds.bundle
 bundles\track_britain\part_057\snds.bundle
 bundles\track_japan\part_053\snds.bundle
 bundles\track_usa\part_053\snds.bundle
```

**I need the first line (line that starts with "copy") to be merged with the remaining lines.
The produced result should look like the following:**

```
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_054\snds.bundle
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_054\snds.bundle bundles\track_belgium\part_025\snds.bundle
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_054\snds.bundle bundles\track_britain\part_057\snds.bundle
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_054\snds.bundle bundles\track_japan\part_053\snds.bundle
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_054\snds.bundle bundles\track_usa\part_053\snds.bundle
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_055\snds.bundle
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_055\snds.bundle bundles\track_belgium\part_026\snds.bundle
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_055\snds.bundle bundles\track_britain\part_058\snds.bundle
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_055\snds.bundle bundles\track_japan\part_054\snds.bundle
copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_055\snds.bundle bundles\track_usa\part_054\snds.bundle
```

***I have thousands of lines like this. Please help me.***

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to delete any newline, unless it is followed by "copy".

Something like this should work for your search pattern:

`\R(?!copy)`

(You need to enable regexes and multi-line in the search and replace dialog).

`(?!...)` is a negative look-ahead.  This means "a newline not followed by the word copy".

Then just replace it with a space (because you want whitespace between the last word of one line and the first word of the next line).

Comment: This is searching and arranging the a two lines into a single column. But i want all the lines should have the word "copy"

Comment: @user1915991, sorry I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use notepad++ macros as follows:

1. Set the cursor at the end of the file
2. From *Marco* menu press *Start Recording*
3. Open the search dialog and type `"\r\ncopy "` (make sure that the search mode is *Extended* and the *Direction* is *Up*) and hit *Find Next*
4. Copy the whole line (maybe using *Home* --> *Shift + End* then copy)
5. Open the replace dialog (*Ctrl + H*) and replace `"\r\n bundles"` with `"\r\n"` + the copied line + `" bundles"`, uncheck *Wrap around*, set the *Direction* to *Down* and hit *Replace All*
6. Hit *Home* to get the start of the line
7. *Stop Recording* from the *Marco* menu
8. Re-run the macro multiple times as needed from the *Macro* menu

Comment: The characters "\" and "t" are not displayed? the output displays:      `copy bundles\track_abudhabi\part_054\snds.bundle`                  
                                **HELP ME**

Comment: Output: `copy bundles rack_abudhabi\part_054\snds.bundle bundles\track_belgium\part_025\snds.bundle`

Comment: aha, i see, replacing with *extended* mode on replaces the `\t` with a tab... and that will cause a problem for any escape character... I think you gotta deal with it depending on the content you expect in the file, like, if you dont have any slashes `/` in your file, just replace all back-slashes \ with slashes before you start the steps above, then replace them back to \ once your done. You can pick any character other than slash for this temp replacement, just some character that does not exist originally in the file

Comment: Running the macro multiple times is not working. The playback Ctrl+shift+p is working but it places the **FIRST** copied text to the lines. Output:`copy bundles/track_australia/part_054/snds.bundle
copy bundles/track_abudhabi/part_054/snds.bundle bundles/track_italy/part_052/snds.bundle
copy bundles/track_abudhabi/part_054/snds.bundle bundles/track_singapore/part_052/snds.bundle
copy bundles/track_abudhabi/part_054/snds.bundle` Same line is copied(The line that i copied FIRST before running the macro).

Comment: Can you help me by building the macro?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, it seems the edits on the replacement dialog are not included in the macro. I think you have to use the python plugin to write your macro, please check this [entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036705/how-to-automate-a-series-of-search-and-replace-operation-in-notepad) and the following [question](http://superuser.com/questions/376288/how-do-i-add-input-to-my-macro-to-replace-text-in-notepad) on superuser

Comment: I dont know how to use it but i downloaded and installed the notepad++ python script.Can you please check and post the steps involved in writing the macro from the BEGINNING.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't worked with python before, and don't have time to do at this time.

Comment: Is there any other way other than using python?

Comment: outside notepad++, you can use any language of your prefer (maybe one you already know), however, it should be easy and quick to learn how to use python for such a task... I can't think of any other way

Comment: OK. I used AUTOHOTKEY script. It's working good. But if i have a python script it would be much easier and faster. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP.