# Multiple word search and replace in notepad++ using a python script

Tags: python, notepad++

I usually use a python script to replace several expressions at once in a txt file.

I create a reference file with my expressions to be replaced, the expressions being separated with space:

```
value1 valueA
value2 valueB
value3 valueC
```

then I use a python script:

```
with open('path to my referencefile.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split()
        editor.replace(s[0], s[1])
```

It normally works but I have an issue when I try to replace expressions which already exist and that I want to re-order basically.

Example:

```
value1 value2
value2 value3
value3 value4
```

In the end value1 will be replaced by value2 then value2 will be replaced by value3. Finally, value3 will be replaced by value4. Which means value1 became value4 instead of value2... How do I keep value1 replaced by value2 instead of this cascade of replacements? (and of course value2 replaced by value3 and value3 by value4)

In notepad++ it's possible using the regex replace function with the formula (value1)|(value2)|(value3) replaced by (?1value2)(?2value3)(?3value4). Is there a way to achieve the same result with the python script mentioned above?

Also, how do you modify the python script to replace expressions only in the selected area of a txt file?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Maybe this tread at codereview will be helpful: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64096/multi-replacement-in-a-string-independently-and-prioritized

Comment: In general, if you have A and B, and want to replace A with B and B with C, you can either work backwards i.e. first B to C then A to B, or first 'park' B as D, then A with B then unpark D as C. More on replace on selected text is [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/13701/python-script-to-replace-on-selection/3)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. The recursive path is probably the way to go

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to automate a series of search and replace operation in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036705/how-to-automate-a-series-of-search-and-replace-operation-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

I have not fully understood the question, but you can use this code.

```
with open("val.txt", "r+") as f:
file = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
for line in file:
    s = line.split()
    s.reverse()
    f.writelines(s[0] + ' ' + s[1] + '\n')
```

This simply changes the two columns. However, I think it is the right way to treat the value of the txt file.

Comment: My question wasn't probably clear enough. I meant I use the text reference file with its two columns to replace those expressions in another text file

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace those two columns in another text file then you can use below code.

```
with open('path to my referencefile.txt') as f:
    another_file = open("another file name","w")
    for l in f:
        s = l.split()
        another_file.write(s[0] + " " + s[0][:-1] + str(int(s[0][-1])+1) + "\n" )
    another_file.close()
```

As you can see, here we are replacing ( not exactly replacing but coping) the **'A'** to **'2'**  in the very first line of the input text file and so on, simultaneously writing down to another file.

If the above code solve the purpose than it fine, else let me know your doubt.

Answer (score -1):

Sample script [Multiples_SR.py](https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/blob/master/scripts/Samples/Multiples_SR.py) from [Python Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/) plugin sample scripts collection does what you need
(see origin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036705/how-to-automate-a-series-of-search-and-replace-operation-in-notepad/69660234#69660234)).

From the explanation of the script:

This script :

Reads an existing "SR_List.txt" file, of the CURRENT directory, containing a list of SEARCH/REPLACEMENT strings, ONE PER line
Selects, one at a time, a COUPLE of SEARCH and REPLACEMENT regexes/expressions/strings/characters
Executes this present S/R on CURRENT edited file, in NOTEPAD++
Loop till the END of the file
Any PURE BLANK line or COMMENT line, beginning with '#', of the "SR_list.txt" file, is simply IGNORED

For EACH line, in the "SR_List.txt" file, the format is

<DELIMITER><SEARCH regex><DELIMITER><REPLACE regex><DELIMITER>

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30140403)

Comment: Why do you post [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69660234/372239) the same answer?

Comment: My initial answer here was just a link to the first answer (to another, similar, question). Have expanded because of @Tranbi's comment. But yes, usefulness is under question.