# RegEx Vertical Replacement

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a simple yet very complicated problem using Notepad++;

I have a file with many instances of the following text:

```
 LODPhases        4
                     0.000000      0.400000        0        1
                     0.400000      0.800000        2        3
                     0.800000      0.920000        4        5
                     0.920000      0.966000        6        6
```

and I want to be able to replace the following part of the text:

```
                     0.000000      0.400000
                     0.400000      0.800000
                     0.800000      0.920000
                     0.920000      0.966000
```

To replace the float values with another set of float values. I do not want to touch anything else, however I do want the expression to match with the `LODPhases       4` at the top. Here's an example of the replaced text:

```
 LODPhases        4
                     0.500000      0.700000        0        1
                     0.300000      0.400000        2        3
                     0.990000      0.550000        4        5
                     0.666000      0.456000        6        6
```

So to summarize, vertically replace the two float value columns ONLY if we find the  `LODPhases        4` text, while leaving the 2 smaller columns to the right alone (as they are not the same for all instances of the text, and vary with each instance). Basically a vertical replacement. I'm aware that you can make a vertical selection using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in Notepad++, however there are thousands of instances like this in my file, and I don't want to spend hours going through every one of them to manually copy them. Is automating something like this possible to do using RegEx?

I hope my question is easy to understand, thank you very much for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: Are you limited to or do you prefer to use native Notepad++ functionality? Can you use other kinds of automation, e.g. PowerShell? Apparently, there's a Python plugin for Notepad++ (albeit dated): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036705/how-to-automate-a-series-of-search-and-replace-operation-in-notepad. Also, looking at the before and after in your example, can you not simply take a substring of every line (assuming the floating column values are always at the end of the line)?

Comment: I would definitely prefer to use native Notepad++ functionality, but if it's not available then I would have no choice to use something else. I have made very basic programs with Python before, so I'm guessing that's where I'm gonna look next if I can't find anything here. I am not sure what you mean by "substring" here, I am not familliar with RegEx terminology if that's that, and the floating values that I want to replace are not at the end of the line, but lay before the 2 smaller collumns to their right (I want to leave the 2 smaller collumns alone). Hope that clears it up!

Comment: I guess another way you can think about it is, I want to select the first two float values and ignore the rest of the line, if the text "LODPhases              4" is present.

Comment: Apologies, I believe I misunderstood the desired "after" text. The second code block is what you want to replace (presumably with, what, spaces?), not what you want to keep. It may make things clearer if you added another code block to denote what exactly the desired _result_ would look like. Also, the whitespace characters, are those tabs or spaces in your text file?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I simply want to replace the set of float values with another set of float values, same number of characters and all. I don't want to replace anything else, however I do have to match "LODPhases 4". I am actually quite close to finishing the problem myself, using the website "regex101.com", however what I need now is a way of ignoring a match. I have done some research now, and there is a lot of talk about "Negative and Positive Lookaheads", but I cannot seem to currently implement them myself. I simply just need a way of ignoring a match expression, to leave it be.

Comment: What are the rules to change `0.000000      0.400000` into `0.500000      0.700000` are they **always** the same values?

Comment: Yes, the middle float values are always the same. The only things that vary with each instance are the two smaller collumns to the right, and I want to leave those be and not touch them. Just replace the middle float values. Hope that explains it!