# Automating routine replaces with PythonScript

Tags: python, notepad++, find-replace

We have a hundreds text files with thousands rows, containing a number of abbreviations we should expand.

**The idea is**:

```
 1. Create an empty vocabulary file (to store find-replace pairs, each on separate line)
 2. Attach a callback function to NOTIFICATION.SEARCHREPLACE  (which should be invoked each time, when find_replace menu dialog occurs and global replace is finished)
 3. For each text file

   3.1. Make globally each find-replace operation from vocabulary (if any), programatically

   3.2. Make another find-replace operations needed (if any), manually   
   3.2.1. For each such operation do (in a callback function of step 2), programatically:

             3.2.1.1. Check if current find-replace pair is already in vocabulary file.
             3.2.1.2. If yes: do nothing. 
Or, as enhancement, update some statistic for that pair <br/>
(like number of replacements or options values, if we decide to keep it in vocabulary -<br/> in a row of pair, in the form of key-value pairs, separated by commas or whatever)

             3.2.1.3. If no:
Create a new line in vocabulary, with find-replace pair <br/> 
(with additional statistics, if we decide to keep it)
```

*Sorry for bad formatting - failed in making long lines shorter..*

This idea already has step 3.1 realised in code. See [how to automate a series of search and replace operation in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036705/how-to-automate-a-series-of-search-and-replace-operation-in-notepad/69660234#69660234).Thanks to stackoverflow community for that.

---

**My question is**:

How to write a callback function of step 2 - to monitor manual (by invoking find&replace menu dialog) find-replace operations? Can't imagine it, and was unable to find a solution within stackoverflow. Even not sure that I need a callback for NOTIFICATION.SEARCHREPLACE - may be, I need a callback for some other event?

Comment: An example of find-replace pairs

, хл-з. маг. -- , хлебо-запасный магазин

, кам. зем. начал. 6 уч. -- , камера земельного начальника 6 участка

, вин. лавка -- , винная лавка

Comment: Why do you want to use Notepad++ ? Write a standalone script, no needs to use Notepad++.

Comment: It's a way. But in this case I need to program find-replace dialog menu and all the other convinuent tools of Notepad++ (sort, convert, syntax lightning etc.)? if I need them for some particular job on the text, for my own.
Abrreviation expanding is not the only possible use - also automatic OCR errors recognition, HTML&XML tag insertion etc.